# React pass component by props's callback get error class constructors must be invoked with 'new'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple page developed using React, the page has a Menu component which has a callback as props (targetPage), when the callback starts, a component is received and then it will be to insert into the page.

But this procedure fails, giving this error,

```
class constructors must be invoked with 'new'
basicStateReducer@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:22501:45
updateReducer@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:22610:26
...
```

this is source code

main app

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
function App() {
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState<any>();
    return (
        <div className="App">
                <Menu
                    targetPage={ (page: any) => {
                        setCurrentPage( page );
                    }}
                />
                <div id={'target-page'}>
                    { !!currentPage ? currentPage : (<img src={'https://localhost/logo'} /) }
                </div>
            </div>
    );
}
export default App;
```

menu component

```js
import pageComponent from '.';
export const Menu = (props:{targetPage:any}) => (
    <div
        onClick={ clickEvent => {
            props.targetPage( pageComponent );
        }}
    >
        click
    </div>
)
```

component

```js
import React from 'react';
export default class pageComponent extends React.Component<any, any> {
    state = {}
    constructor(props: any) {
        super( props );
    }
    render() {
        let content = (
            <div>Page</div>
        );
        return content;
    }
}
```

how can I does it get a component from a callback passed as porps?

Comment: It's not really clear but are you trying to implement your own routing system (click on a menu item and show the corresponding "page)?